# Ajax calendar not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using Ajax Calendar for date picker. when i click the calendar image the page will get postback but the calendar popup windows is not getting popup. How to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_FromDate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
              ontextchanged="txt_FromDate_TextChanged>
 </asp:TextBox>
 <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="cal_FromDate" PopupButtonID="ibtnFromDate"
                       runat="server" TargetControlID="txt_FromDate"
                       Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
 </cc1:CalendarExtender>     
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnFromDate" 
                  ImageUrl="~/_layouts/images/PayrollImages/calendar.gif" 
                  ImageAlign="Bottom" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: why are you using autopostback?

Comment: @user3295669 The posted code worked fine for me ..!

Comment: i guess the problem is not with the calendar extender, check for the reason why the postback appears? where you are wrapping in the calendar extender code?? can you please show us the code??

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="btn1" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>

<asp:ImageButton ID="img1" runat="server"
                 ImageUrl="~/_layouts/images/PayrollImages/calendar.gif"/>

<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="calendar1" runat="server" PopupButtonID="img1"   
                      TargetControlID="btn1" Enabled="True">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_from" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" runat="server" 
             AutoPostBack="True" ontextchanged="txt_from_TextChanged">
</asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txt_from_CalendarExtender" runat="server"
                      Format="MM/dd/yyyy" Enabled="True"
                      TargetControlID="txt_from">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

no need to use image button for calendar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" runat="server"  Width="50%"></asp:TextBox>

<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtDOB_CalendarExtender" runat="server"
                      TargetControlID="txtDOB"
                      Format="MM/dd/yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgDate" 
                      PopupPosition="BottomLeft">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>

<asp:Image ID="imgDate" AlternateText="Image Date"
           ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar.png" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You are just missing a Property of CalanderExtender     **PopupButtonID**. try the following

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_FromDate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
             ontextchanged="txt_FromDate_TextChanged">
</asp:TextBox>

<asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnFromDate"
                 ImageUrl="~/_layouts/images/PayrollImages/calendar.gif" 
                 ImageAlign="Bottom" runat="server"/>

<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="cal_FromDate" PopupButtonID="ibtnFromDate"
                      runat="server" PopupButtonID="ibtnFromDate" 
                      TargetControlID="txt_FromDate" Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: -1 He is not misiing 'PopupButtonID' , You are wrong